# How do I create arrays of events and output in week-based calendar format?

Tags: java

I have a constructor below. How do I write an array of Event like

```
Event[] September = new Event[30];    
Event[] October = new Event[31];
```

How do i produce an output such as this

[image]

```
class Event
{
  private String TimeofEvent;
  private String startingTime;
  private int priority;

  public Event(String TimeofEvent, String startingTime, int priority)
  {

    this.TimeofEvent = TimeofEvent;
    this.startingTime = startingTime;
    this.priority = (int)(Math.random() *3) + 1;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return "TimeofEvent: " + TimeofEvent + " " + "Starting Time: " + startingTime + " " + "Priority: " + " " +priority;
  }
```

Comment: (1) You probably shouldn't arrange arrays of `Event` as if they are days. Are there going to be only 31 events in October? Can't there be more than one event in a day? (2) This seems to be some part of a homework assignment. As such, you should make your own attempt at solving it, and then come back and ask. Besides, there is not enough information here, as we don't know the constraints and the required output.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to use a HashMap to store your Objects if that is the issue.

To get the output right I would play around with the  [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: Problem is its based on Classes and Objects and I am not suppose to use  something that advance

Comment: @Aurora_Titanium Hmm. Then ArrayList is your friend. ArrayList allows you to store the Events and to print them out in text format you can just make a loop which prints a space between each date and a new line after every 7 days.